# Firebase Database Groupby Using

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

For Example: My firebase database has to following datas.

```
datas=[{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 }, 
{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 }, 
{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 }, 
{ "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 }, 
{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 }, 
{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } ];
```

How to make the Firebase Database equivalent of this SQL query:

```
SELECT category, sum(hits), sum(bytes) 
FROM datas 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY sum(bytes) DESC
```

Comment: Firebase is a NoSQL database and has no concept of a `GROUP BY` clause for its queries. As stated now it's hard to help you (it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) beyond recommending reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching our video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). If you have a specific use case, we may be able to help more concretely.

Comment: If you have more information, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40932423/edit). Putting it in the comments typically is not very readable.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your advices. I edited.